# BASH: Iterating two v ariables in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, iteration

I am having two files numbers.txt(1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5 \n) and alpha.txt (a \n n \n c \n d \n e \n)

Now I want to iterate both the files at the same time something like.

```
   for num in `cat numbers.txt` && alpha in `cat alpha.txt`
   do 
   echo $num "blah" $alpha
   done
```

Or other idea I  was having is

```
   for num in `cat numbers.txt`
   do
     for alpha in `cat alpha.txt`
     do
      echo $num 'and' $alpha
      break
     done
   done
```

but this kind of code always take the first value of $alpha.

I hope my problem is clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

---

Here it is what I actually intended to do. (Its just an example)

I am having one more file say template.txt having content.

```
    variable1= NUMBER
    variable2= ALPHA
```

I wanted to take the output from two files i.e numbers.txt and alpha.txt(one line from both at a time) and want to replace the NUMBER and ALPHA with the respective content from those two files.

so here it what I did as i got to know how to iterate both files together.

```
    paste number.txt alpha.txt | while read num alpha
    do 
     cp template.txt  temp.txt
     sed -i "{s/NUMBER/$num/g}" temp.txt
     sed -i "{s/ALPHA/$alpha/g}" temp.txt
     cat temp.txt >> final.txt
    done
```

Now what i am having in final.txt is:

```
    variable1= 1
    variable2= a
    variable1= 2
    variable2= b
    variable1= 3
    variable2= c
    variable1= 4
    variable2= d
    variable1= 5
    variable2= e
    variable1= 6
    variable2= f
    variable1= 7
    variable2= g
    variable1= 8
    variable2= h
    variable1= 9
    variable2= i
    variable1= 10
    variable2= j
```

Its very simple and stupid approach. I wanted to know is there any other way to do this??

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I wish you made your question more clearer.. What sort of output you are looking:

1 and a
2 and b
.....

OR

1 and a
1 and b
1 and c
...
2 and a
2 and b
....
....
5 and a
..

Comment: Do not worry about the output I just want to iterate both the variable together

Comment: `for x in $(cat ...)` is always wrong. `while` is the correct way to iterate over a file. And don't use backticks.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I was going through after long time. please advise me why it is wrong to use `for` and backticks?

Comment: Please see "[How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)", "[Why you don't read lines with 'for'](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)" and "[Why is $(...) preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your question isn't clear enough. Specifically, the way you wish to iterate through your files is unclear, but assuming you want to have an output such as:

```
1 blah a
2 blah b
3 blah c
4 blah d
5 blah e
```

you can use the `paste` utility, like this:

```
paste number.txt alpha.txt | while read alpha num ; do
    echo "$num and $alpha"
done
```

or even:

```
paste -d@ alpha num | sed 's/@/ blah /'
```

Comment: The only thing I wanted it to iterate both the value together..

it will solve the problem thanks alot...

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop is impossible in bash. Your second one, without the `break`, would combine **each** line from numbers.txt with **each** line from alpha.txt, like this:

```
1 AND a
1 AND n 
1 AND c
...
2 AND a
...
3 AND a
...
4 AND a
...
```

Your `break` makes it skip all lines from the alpha.txt, except the 1st one (bmk has already explained it in his answer)

It should be possible to organize the correct loop using the **while loop** construction, but it would be rather ugly.

There're lots of easier alternatives which maybe a better choice, depending on specifics of your task. For example, you could try this:

```
  paste numbers.txt alpha.txt
```

or, if you really want your "AND"s, then, something like this:

```
  paste numbers.txt alpha.txt | sed 's/\t/ AND /'
```

And if your numbers are really sequential (and you can live without 'AND'), you can simply do:

```
  cat -n alpha.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate solution according to the first model you suggested:

```
while read -u 5 a && read -u 6 b
do
   echo $a $b
done 5<numbers.txt 6<alpha.txt
```

The notation `5<numbers.txt` tells the shell to open `numbers.txt using file descriptor 5.  read -u 5 a means read from a value for a from file descriptor 5, which has been associated with numbers.txt`.

The advantage of this approach over paste is that it gives you fine-grain control over how you merge the two files.  For example you could read one line from the first file and twice from the second file.

Comment: @Larry, You saved  my day today. I was trying to read from 2 files. One with custom IFS value and normally and it worked. :) Thanks alot

Comment: @larry so here file descriptor will be of bash process ID?

Answer (score 1):

In your second example the inner loop is executed only once because of the `break`. It will simply jump out of the loop, i.e. you will always only get the first element of `alpha.txt`. Therefore I think you should remove it:

```
for num in `cat numbers.txt`
do
  for alpha in `cat alpha.txt`
  do
    echo $num 'and' $alpha
    done
done
```

Comment: This will output "1 AND a", "1 AND n", "1 AND c", ... "2 AND a", ... I suppose, @asked wants to have "1 AND a", "2 AND n", "3 AND c", ...

Comment: @Alexis: In that case I guess your answer is better. But at least I explained why only the first value of `alpha.txt` was considered...

Comment: This will not solve the purpose.
It will iterate $alpha for every value of $num.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple loop isn't specifically your requirement but getting corresponding lines is then you may try the following code:

```
for line in `cat numbers.txt`
do
   echo $line "and" $(cat alpha.txt| head -n$line | tail -n1 )
done
```

The `head` gets you the number of lines equal to the value of line and `tail` gets you the last element.

Comment: The numbers.txt is not necessary to be numeric it just an example..we can keep count of which time it is  iterating and that will solve the prooblem

Answer (score 0):

@tollboy, I think the answer you are looking for is this:

```
count=1
for item in $(paste number.txt alpha.txt); do
  if [[ "${item}" =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
    echo "variable${count}= ${item}" >> final.txt
  elif [[ "${item}" =~ [0-9] ]]; then
    echo "variable${count}= ${item}" >> final.txt
  fi
  count=$((count+1))
done
```

When you type `paste number.txt alpha.txt` in your console, you see:

```
1        a
2        b
3        c
4        d
5        e
6        f
7        g
8        h
9        i
10       j
```

From bash's point of view `$(paste number.txt alpha.txt)` it looks like this:

```
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g 8 h 9 i 10 j
```

So for each item in that list, figure out if it is alpha or numeric, and print it to the output file.

Lastly, increment the count.